# Put the last 8 bits of a big.Int into a uint8

Tags: type-conversion, go

I'm trying to write a password generator. It requires that characters be in ASCII representation, but I'm trying to use `crypto/rand`. This provides numbers in `big.Int` format, though, and I need to convert the relevant lower 8 bits to a form usable in a string. I've tried converting from `big.Int` to `uint8` with no luck so far.

Is there a good and easy method to do this? I have seen answers involving using `encoding/binary` to convert from `int64` to `[8]uint8`, but those seem needlessly complex for my purpose. Any guidance at all would be appreciated :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get bytes out of `crypto/rand`, I'd skip the use of `big.Int` and `rand.Int()` entirely and use either `rand.Read()` or `rand.Reader`:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "fmt"
    "io"
)

// If you want just a byte at a time ...
// (you could change 'byte' to int8 if you prefer)    
func secureRandomByte() byte {
    data := make([]byte, 1)
    if _, err := rand.Read(data); err != nil {
        // handle error
        panic(err)
    }
    return data[0]
}

// If you want to read multiple bytes at a time ...
func genPassword(len int) (string, error) {
    data := make([]byte, len)
    if _, err := io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, data); err != nil {
        // handle error
        return "", err
    }
    for i := range data {
        // XXX quick munge into something printable
        data[i] &= 0x3F
        data[i] += 0x20
    }
    return string(data), nil
}

func main() {
    b := secureRandomByte()
    fmt.Printf("%T = %v\n", b, b)
    fmt.Println(genPassword(16))
}
```

Comment: Very helpful to know, and I believe I'll implement this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "math/big"
)

func main() {
        mpInt := big.NewInt(0x123456789abcdef0)
        b := byte(mpInt.Int64())
        fmt.Printf("%02x", b)
}
```

---

```
f0
```

In action: http://play.golang.org/p/92PbLdiVsP

---

EDIT: Evan Shaw correctly points out in a comment bellow that the above code is actually incorrect for big Ints outside of `int64` limits. Instead of pulling it from `big.Bytes` (which makes a copy of all of the bits representing a `big.Int` IIRC) it's probably more performant to use `big.And`:

---

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "math/big"
)

func lsB(n *big.Int) byte {
        var m big.Int
        return byte(m.And(m.SetInt64(255), n).Int64())
}

func main() {
        var mpInt big.Int
        if _, ok := mpInt.SetString("0x123456789abcdef012342", 0); !ok {
                log.Fatal()
        }

        fmt.Printf("%02x", lsB(&mpInt))
}
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/pgkGEFgb8-

Comment: Although this will work in practice, the the result of `Int64()` is documented to be undefined when the value won't fit in an int64. A more correct (though more inefficient) way of doing it would be to use the `Bytes()` method.